Bigfoot and alphalph
I am currently typesetting a critical scholarly edition that features multiple footnote apparatus. One of them is numbered with letters. The footnote counters are not resetted per page, but per document edited. So there could easily be over a hundred footnotes per document. For this scenario I use the bigfoot package which allows to define additional types of footnotes.
My problem is, that the option "alph" just allows the letters "a" to "z", so i can have max. 26 critical footnotes. Therefore I am getting the error "! LaTeX Error: Counter too large."
I am aware, that there also exists a package called "alphalph" which supports more than 26 letters continuing with "aa, ab" and so on.
How can I combine the bigfoot and the alphalph package to make that work? I have no idea how to override the option alph for the \DeclareNewFootnote command.
Example:
\documentclass{book}
\RequirePackage{alphalph}
\RequirePackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A} % This is for non critical footnotes like comments
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph] % This is for critical footnotes

\begin{document}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 1\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 2\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 3\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 4\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 5\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 6\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 7\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 8\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 9\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 10\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 11\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 12\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 13\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 14\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 15\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 16\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 17\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 18\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 19\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 20\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 21\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 22\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 23\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 24\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 25\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 26\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 27\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 28\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 29\footnoteB{Foo}
    This is critical footnote Nr. 30\footnoteB{Foo}
\end{document}


Welcome to tex.sx.

It is actually easy enough to solve
Use
\usepackage{alphalph}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B} % This is for critical footnotes
\renewcommand*{\thefootnoteB}{\alphalph{\value{footnoteB}}} 

internally manyfoot (loaded by bigfoot) is expecting to be able to use \@<formatter>, say \@alph (if the optional [alph] is used), but this is not available for alphalph.
In this case it is not needed at all, just define the footnote series at normal, without the optional argument, and then manually change the visual representation of the counter for footnoteB, where we can now easily to use \alphalph.
It was found in this deleted answer (some of us can see it) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234329/3929 (just to credit the answer where I got it)

Thank you very much, this works as expected! Nice solution!
